# Write a JavaScript program to extract the first half of a string of even length - "x is not defined"

Tags: javascript

I have to make a "JS program to extract the first half of a string of even length." I've tried to do it this way:

```js
function check(string) {
    if(string.length % 2 == 0) {
        const x = (string.length/2);
    }
    else {
        const x = (string.length/2)-1;
    }
    const string2 = string.substring(0, x);
}

check("JavaScript");
```

but I'm getting `x is not defined`. What's wrong?

Comment: `const` has block scope, so only is defined within enclosing brace pair.

Comment: You are defining x inside an if/else so it is not available outside of it.

Comment: What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Define x outside the if/else.

Comment: I didn't know how to do it properly (thought I somehow can still do it with const) but now I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your variable `const x` is out of scope because is enclosed within the `if-else` block.
- Declare that variable as `var` or `let`

```js
function check(string) {
  let x;
  if (string.length % 2 == 0) {
    x = (string.length / 2);
  } else {
    x = (string.length / 2) - 1;
  }
  const string2 = string.substring(0, x);
  console.log(string2)
}

check("JavaScript");
```

Comment: Var shouldn't be used anymore as far as I know. Am I right? Btw, I will accept your answer, thanks a lot

Comment: @f0rta that's not true. There are still plenty of valid use-cases for `var`, including backwards compatibility and forcing non-lexical scope for the variable in `for` loops, though that second one is quite in-depth.

Comment: I will definitely look up. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I beat you by one second and yet you get two upvotes while I get zero. Stack Overflow makes so much sense.

Comment: I don't have enough rep, I'd +1 you for your great answer man. I really hope you understand why I chose his answer

Answer (score 0):

Declare in the function scope using `let` so that you can later assign the variable's value within the `if/else` statements:

```js
function check(string) {
  let x;

  if (string.length % 2 == 0) {
    x = (string.length / 2);
  } else {
    x = (string.length / 2) - 1;
  }

  return string.substring(0, x);
}

const half = check("JavaScript");

console.log(half);
```

Alternatively, you can condense the `if/else` into a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and still use `const`:

```js
function check(string) {
  const x = string.length % 2 == 0
    ? (string.length / 2)
    : (string.length / 2) - 1;

  return string.substring(0, x);
}

const half = check("JavaScript");

console.log(half);
```

### Update

You do not want to initialize `x` without first declaring it using `let` or `var`, otherwise it will be implicitly defined as a global in non-strict mode, or throw an error in strict mode:

#### non-strict mode

```js
function test () {
  // non-strict mode
  x = 5;
}

test();

console.log(window.x);
```

#### strict mode

```js
function test () {
  'use strict';
  x = 5;
}

test();

console.log(window.x);
```

Comment: Great answer. I knew it, but I thought there should be a way to somehow still use the const and it felt like I was missing something. I would accept your answer as correct, but I will take Ele's one just because he has less rep than you and both of you responded at the same time haha :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, what would be the difference between using if(){x=;} without defining x with let x before and using if(){x=;} with let x before?

Comment: @f0rta Without `let`, `x` would be implicitly defined as a global variable.

Comment: I don't think I explained it right, because it actually works both ways... so actually what's the difference between that function with let x added and without it? Both ways work properly

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments `const` has block scope, so the `x` variable is not known outside the block it is declared in.

As alternative to other solutions, you can still use `const` provided you use a smarter expression (which also corrects a problem with your second expression):

```
const x = (string.length - string.length % 2) / 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is better way better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Your "x is undefined" issue has been answered by others.

So I'll just say that you don't need to perform the calculation two different ways. It seems that you want odd numbers to be rounded down. Therefore you could use:

`x = Math.floor(string.length / 2);`

- Math.floor() = round down
- Math.ceil() = round up
- Math.round() = round to closest whole number

You should probably `return` the result too, rather than just assign it to another string:

`return string.substring(0, x);`

Comment: const check = (str) => str.substring(0, Math.floor(str.length / 2))

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to return it because I encountered that error and I didn't continue. That's a big issue for me. I always assign to another string and return that string. I don't know why, it just feels unnatural for me atm to return something like string.substring().

Comment: Sometimes the more verbose way is better - it more clearly shows the intent. You can tell from my comment above that I am a bit of a fan of doing it all in one go. It's a phase I'm going through :)

Comment: When you are passing in a callback/delegate to an event handler, or handling a Promise then you might become tempted by the more compact lines...